# Tuning SQL Updation query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using this update query which is taking about 8hrs to execute, I want it to take lesser time, how can I do that? My query is:

```
BEGIN
      LOOP
         UPDATE  ENCORE_LIVE.INSTRUMENT_CLASSIFICATION SET CODE = NULL WHERE TYPE_ID =
         15 AND CODE is not NULL
         and rownum < 50000;

         exit when SQL%rowcount < 49999;
         commit;
      END LOOP;
      commit;
END;
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Its only updating 50,000 records for this condition, whereas I have 22468909 records for above condition.

Comment: Any idea how long it takes without making those batches?

Comment: why are you not just running the single update statement? If it's due to running out of UNDO space and if this is a statement that's run regularly (as opposed to one-off, ad-hoc updates), then I highly recommend you ask your DBAs to increase the UNDO space to accommodate this statement.

Comment: Why dont you go with BULK COLLECT and FORALL if needed to be done in batches.

Comment: @AvrajitRoy that would make things even slower - select the data, fetch it into arrays (i.e. in memory) and then do the update, vs just doing the update.

Answer (score 1):

So you are updating a table in batches of 50 000 records, right?

You should verify if you have columns `TYPE_ID` and `CODE` in `INSTRUMENT_CLASSIFICATION` table  indexed and eventually create indexes.

Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32234901/2224701).

Your UPDATE query is basic and cannot be optimized anyhow. To create an index you can use:

```
CREATE INDEX instrumentClasification_TypeCode_idx
     ON ENCORE_LIVE.INSTRUMENT_CLASSIFICATION
        (TYPE_ID, CODE)
```

Also you should consider running the update query in one batch without splitting it in batches.

Comment: I don't know much about indexing, since new to Database, can u please provide me the query so that it may take less time to update.

Comment: @SuyashGupta: Vojtěch has suggested an index for you, why not try that? Run that on a test database and adjust it to your needs. Remember that Stack Overflow is not a clearing-house for free labour - when you receive an answer you are expected to do the implementation work.

Comment: I have created index as per the above code, Now can u please provide me the query as an alternate of mine earlier query?

Comment: And the result was - is it faster or slower or the same? There is not much to improve in SQL, except for @Boneist comment.

Comment: should I run the same query now , I mean I have created an index name-> instrumentClasification_TypeCode_idx  now how to use that?

Comment: @SuyashGupta Yes, your query is OK, only running in batches and without indexes can make it run slower.